# Exoplayer how to update custom actions of PlayerNotificationManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So basically I have slightly simplified [UAMP](https://github.com/android/uamp) player.

I want to set custom action (add/remove like) on foreground notification  and change icon dynamically:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ND9.png)

Here is my code for PlayerNotificationManager wrapper:

```
const val ACTION_REMOVE_LIKE = "com.romeat.smashup.media.REMOVE_LIKE_FROM_TRACK"
const val ACTION_ADD_LIKE = "com.romeat.smashup.media.ADD_LIKE_TO_TRACK"

/**
 * A wrapper class for ExoPlayer's PlayerNotificationManager.
 */
internal class SmashupNotificationManager(
    private val context: Context,
    private val sessionToken: MediaSessionCompat.Token,
    notificationListener: PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener
) {

    private var notificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager
    private var builder: PlayerNotificationManager.Builder  
    private val platformNotificationManager: NotificationManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    init {
        val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)

        builder = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(
            context, 
            NOW_PLAYING_NOTIFICATION_ID, 
            NOW_PLAYING_CHANNEL_ID)
            
        with (builder) {
            setMediaDescriptionAdapter(DescriptionAdapter(mediaController))
            setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
            setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.notification_channel)
            setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.notification_channel_description)

            setCustomActionReceiver(
                object : PlayerNotificationManager.CustomActionReceiver {
                    override fun createCustomActions(
                        context: Context,
                        instanceId: Int
                    ): MutableMap<String, NotificationCompat.Action> {
                        return mutableMapOf(
                            Pair(ACTION_ADD_LIKE, NotificationCompat.Action(
                                R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_border_24, "add like",
                                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                    context, 
                                    123, 
                                    Intent(ACTION_ADD_LIKE).setPackage(context.packageName),
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                                )
                            )),
                        )
                    }

                    override fun getCustomActions(player: Player): MutableList<String> {
                        return mutableListOf(ACTION_ADD_LIKE)
                    }

                    override fun onCustomAction(player: Player, action: String, intent: Intent) { }
                }
            )
        }
        notificationManager = builder.build()
        notificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(sessionToken)
        notificationManager.setUseRewindAction(false)
        notificationManager.setUseFastForwardAction(false)
    }

    fun updateLikeButton() {
        // Can get here with no problem.
        // Basically I want to replace CustomActionReceiver:
        builder.setCustomActionReceiver(object : PlayerNotificationManager.CustomActionReceiver {
            override fun createCustomActions(
                context: Context,
                instanceId: Int
            ): MutableMap<String, NotificationCompat.Action> {
                return mutableMapOf(
                    Pair(ACTION_REMOVE_LIKE, NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24, "remove like",
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            context, 
                            123, 
                            Intent(ACTION_REMOVE_LIKE).setPackage(context.packageName), 
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                        )
                    ))
                )
            }

            override fun getCustomActions(player: Player): MutableList<String> {
                return mutableListOf(ACTION_REMOVE_LIKE)
            }

            override fun onCustomAction(player: Player, action: String, intent: Intent) { }
        })

        ... 
        
        // But I can't use .notify() because second parameter is of PlayerNotificationManager type, not Notification type
        platformNotificationManager.notify(NOW_PLAYING_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
    }
    
    // other code, like DescriptionAdapter etc...

}
```

I managed to set custom action and respond to press event, but I can't find a way to change the icon.
I am trying to replace `CustomActionReceiver` in my `updateLikeButton()` function, but there is no way to call `notify()` and update notification itself.

I am curious is it even possible to do with `PlayerNotificationManager` in general?

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot, I discovered that MutableMap is what does the magic

```
private var customActionRepeat: NotificationCompat.Action? = null
private var customPendingAction: PendingIntent? = null
private val repeatAction = "repeatAction"
private val repeatActionOff = "actionOff"
private val repeatActionOn = "actionOn"
private var customActionMutableMap: MutableMap<String, NotificationCompat.Action>? = mutableMapOf()
private var customActionReceiver = CustomActionReceiver()
//set the customActionReceiver to your PlayerNotificationManager

onCreate(){
    customPendingAction = PendingIntent.getService(
        this, 0,
        Intent(this, PlayerService::class.java).apply {
            action = Constants.ACTION_REPEAT
        }, if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        } else {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        }
    )
    customActionRepeat = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
        R.drawable.repeat_on,
        "Repeat on",
        customPendingAction
    ).build()
    customActionMutableMap!![repeatAction] = customActionRepeat!!
}

private inner class CustomActionReceiver : PlayerNotificationManager.CustomActionReceiver {
    override fun createCustomActions(
        context: Context,
        instanceId: Int
    ): MutableMap<String, NotificationCompat.Action> {
        return customActionMutableMap!!
    }

    override fun getCustomActions(player: Player): MutableList<String> {
        return mutableListOf(repeatAction)
    }

    override fun onCustomAction(player: Player, action: String, intent: Intent) {
        when(action){
            repeatActionOn ->{
                player.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
                repeatMode.value = RepeatModeUtil.REPEAT_TOGGLE_MODE_ONE

                customActionRepeat = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                    R.drawable.repeat_one_on,
                    "Repeat one on",
                    customPendingAction
                ).build()
                customActionMutableMap!![repeatAction] = customActionRepeat!!
            }
            repeatActionOff ->{
                player.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
                repeatMode.value = RepeatModeUtil.REPEAT_TOGGLE_MODE_ALL

                customActionRepeat = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                    R.drawable.repeat_on,
                    "Repeat on",
                    customPendingAction
                ).build()
                customActionMutableMap!![repeatAction] = customActionRepeat!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so call it that

```
    //to turn on
customActionReceiver.onCustomAction(
    player = mediaSession?.player!!,
    action = repeatActionOn,
    intent = Intent(this, PlayerService::class.java)
)

//to turn off
customActionReceiver.onCustomAction(
    player = mediaSession?.player!!,
    action = repeatActionOff,
    intent = Intent(this, PlayerService::class.java)
)
```

[image]